# Gradually change/transition background color of input using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I slowly fade in a new background color using only javascript?

Currently I'm changing the background color as follows:

```
// html
<input onfocus="onFocus(this)" onblur="onFocus(this)" type="text">

// JS
function onFocus(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

Is there a way using only JS to make this transition slowly to yellow?  I want the transition to be over 5 seconds.

Thanks!

Edit: I am aware that you *could* do this with css, but I am trying to do this purely with setInterval or setTimeout.
The answer it to simply use setInterval() and gradually change the color that way.

Answer (score 0):

For **transition CSS**
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
   transition: background 6s; 
   transition: {css-attribute} {time(seconds)};
```

I don't know you want to **stay yellow on first focus?**

or **only focus will yellow when move out will back to normal**.

```js
function onFocus(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

```css
input{
  transition: background 6s; /*only add this!*/
  -webkit-transition: background 6s; 
  /*Some older browsers need specific prefixes (-webkit-)*/
}
```

```html
<input onfocus="onFocus(this)" onblur="onFocus(this)" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this.

```css
input {
  background: white;
  transition: background 5s;
}

input:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

for transition: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```js
function onFocus(x) {
    x.style.background = "yellow";
}

function onBlur(x) {
    x.style.background = "white";
}
```

```css
.trans {
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<input class="trans"onfocus="onFocus(this)" onblur="onBlur(this)" type="text">
```